# how to read Twitter's emoji

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, unicode

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to write or (to encode) twitter's emoji.. For example this [following tweet](http://pic.twitter.com/kREJrvmXy2) has some emojis so I would like to know if there is a way to write the proper unicode in json

```
for item in r:
    with io.open('live_tweets/'+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys = True, indent = 4))
    print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

result

```
...
"text": "RT @AlkofahiGhaleb: @MarionSpekker danke thank you\nHave a great time",
...
```

Can the emojis be replaced by unicode characters?

Comment: Those look like Unicode characters to me.